# Dynamically insert img source in an unordered list li tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to dynamically insert image source but it is having some problems with the orientation of the image. 
My code looks like this.

```
$.each(mydata, function(index, data){
    $('#data').append('<li>+ <img src='+mydata[index].team.crestUrl +'>
    <a id="to_details" href="#">'+'<span id="'+ index +'" class="ui">' + 
      mydata[index].team.name +'</span></a></li>');
```

With below change the image does not appear at all:

```
$.each(mydata, function(index, data){
    $('#data').append('<li> <img src='+mydata[index].team.crestUrl +'> 
    <a id="to_details" href="#">'+'<span id="'+ index +'" class="ui">' + 
       mydata[index].team.name +'</span></a></li>');
```

An example is given in the images

[image: An example is given in the images]

I tried many ways but its still not working for me.

Comment: The problem could be with css. I don't see any issue in the jqeury (the first one).

Comment: Plunkr would help. I second @ChengHuiYuan - this looks like a css issue.

Comment: I am  using this for css. Maybe it has something to do with Jquery mobile in specific.
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />`

Comment: You appear to be trying to use multi-line single-quoted strings. That is not possible in JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

Building HTML strings is usually pretty messy and can lead to problems with character encoding and string literal termination (as you are seeing).

I find it best to construct elements instead of strings. For example

```js
$('#data').append(mydata.map(({ team }, index) => $('<li>').append([
  $('<img>', { src: team.crestUrl }),
  $('<a>', { id: 'to_details', href: '#' }).append($('<span>', {
    id: index, 
    class: 'ui',
    text: team.name
  }))
])))
```

```js
const mydata = [{
  team: { name: 'Team #1', crestUrl: 'https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=Team+1+Crest' },
}, {
  team: { name: 'Team #2', crestUrl: 'https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=Team+2+Crest' },
}]

$('#data').append(mydata.map(({ team }, index) => $('<li>').append([
  $('<img>', { src: team.crestUrl }),
  $('<a>', { id: 'to_details', href: '#' }).append($('<span>', {
    id: index, 
    class: 'ui',
    text: team.name
  }))
])))
```

```css
ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
li { display: flex; margin: 1rem 0; align-items: center; }
li img { margin-right: 1rem; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="data"></ul>
```

Comment: Passing an object literal as attributes is a pretty awesome. Didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @max yeah, I only learnt that one recently too. Mind you, I don't do a lot of jQuery these days ;)